# Is there a way to add a pop up selectable menu with Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's an example of the kind of menu that I mean in iOS:

[image]

Comment: Please have a look this package if it helps you https://github.com/SKLn-Rad/Xam.Plugin.PopupMenu

Answer (score 3):

You can make your custom popup using Rg.Popup. Check below URL for more info,
[Rg.Popup for Custom Popups](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)

Answer (score 2):

The menu in the screenshot is a Pop-up called "Action Sheet" in iOS.
You can display it like that (copied from the [xamarin.forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/pop-ups) documentary)

```
async void OnActionSheetSimpleClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string action = await DisplayActionSheet ("ActionSheet: Send to?", "Cancel", null, "Email", "Twitter", "Facebook");
  Debug.WriteLine ("Action: " + action);
}
```

As an alternative you could use this library for displaying pop ups in Xamarin (it features Action Sheets aswell): https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs